# How to change MQTT hostname for Google Iot Core

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

I am working on an iot device using google-cloud-iot-core, but i would like to have allow for 3rd party support, so i want to change the host name of the mqtt, how can it be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need a bit more detail on what exactly you're trying to do? The MQTT host name, meaning mqtt.googleapis.com ? That hostname? Without sending the messages to that endpoint, you won't be using IoT Core anymore. :) Which is fine, but then I need to know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes the mqtt.googleapis.com hostname, i want to change that.
I want to do that to expose the IoT Core to 3rd party applications, where they can pub/sub and it will trigger Cloud Functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change that endpoint, then you're no longer talking to IoT Core. It's not configurable, as that's the endpoint to talk to the service.

You can setup your own MQTT server somewhere else (could do it in GCE or GKE with a custom container) and make the hostname whatever you want, and then setup your own broker to take the MQTT payloads and create Pub/Sub messages, or even to act as a forwarding proxy to IoT Core itself I suppose (although security and auth might get a bit odd).

Or you could even just go directly to Pub/Sub. It all just depends on your need.

As I mentioned, changing the hostname for IoT Core (the mqtt.googleapis.com) it means that you aren't using IoT Core any longer. There's no other way to access the communication broker piece of IoT Core to do the Pub/Sub message creation, etc. If you don't use the IoT Core endpoint (hostname) then you'd be on your own for creating the Pub/Sub messages from the IoT device data.

Comment: I tried proxy but as you mentioned had issues with ssl and auth, is there a simpler way to reroute traffic to mqtt.googleapi.com. Just forwarding it rather then creating a broker with Pub/Sub. Any documentation or blog?

Comment: Not for this specific use-case, no unfortunately. We aren't fully supporting devices talking through another one to IoT Core yet. We have some samples/docs planned, but haven't written them yet. In fairness, we're not even GA yet (still open beta). :) They will come, just don't have them yet.

Comment: It would be really great to have them so that we can add support for 3rd party app integration using google platforms